# NodeJS - Show MySQL inside the HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am trying to show MySQL Database inside an html file, i already tried to show it in console and it works , but how can i show it in the html file?

here is my code inside index.js.

my html file is located in public folder though.

```
    var http = require("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    path = require("path"),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    port = process.argv[2] || 88;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname
    , filename = path.join(process.cwd(), "/public/" + uri);
  var contentTypesByExtension = {
    '.html': "text/html",
    '.css':  "text/css",
    '.js':   "text/javascript"
  };
  fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    if(!exists) {
      response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("404 - Page Not Found.\n");
      response.end();
      return;
    }
    if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) filename += '/index.html';
    fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
      if(err) {        
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(err + "\n");
        response.end();
        return;
      }
      var headers = {};
      var contentType = contentTypesByExtension[path.extname("/public/" + filename)];
      if (contentType) headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;
      response.writeHead(200, headers);
      response.write(file, "binary");
      response.end();
    });
  });
}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'nouwontgetit',
      database : 'databasename',
    }
);

connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM posts';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log('posts name: ', rows[i].name);
    }
});

connection.end();


console.log("Static file server running at\n  => http://localhost:" + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Instead of `console.log`, you could create a String before your `for` loop, inside it do `html += 'posts name: ' + rows[i].name + '<br>';`, and after it `response.write(html);` (don't forget the headers, and to `.end()` your response).

Comment: @blex thanks, but what if i want to show it inside a specific div?

Comment: At this point you should really consider using templates (and Express or similar framework) instead.

Comment: @mscdex is right, doing all of this in there is going to be messy. Search for NodeJS template engines (You can then easily inject dynamic content into your templates)

Comment: Alright , thanks guys , i will try to do that. 
but ,can you tell me a good template engine to do so? although i don't want something really big.

Comment: Your last comment is asking for an opinion about a "good engine". Just google for "node.js template engine" and you will find something that will suit your needs. We do not know what you would value as a "good" engine.

Comment: uh , okay...thanks anyways.